# YAHOO! Place Finder API

Tags: geocoding, yahoo-api, yahoo-maps

Is there a way to get all of the POI (Points of Interest) and AOI (Areas of Interest) lets say for a specific state.

I would like to be able to auto-complete while someone is typing if it contains any of that data, but I don't know how to get a list of all that data.

I would even be good with storing it my database if need be, because I can't see it changing very often.

Answer (score 0):

No, PlaceFinder itself does not provide a way to download its places database. It's only intended for individual lookups.

You might look at the [GeoPlanet data downloads](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/data/) which make available under CC license the entire WOEID (Where on Earth ID) geo database.